# How to calculate the monodromy matrix of the following ODE system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:
$$
\frac{dw}{dt} = (-V(t)+\frac{1}{\lambda}F(t)) w,
$$
with $t>0$ and parameter $\lambda>0$

The matrices $F(t)$ and $V(t)$ take the form
$$
F(t)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & (1-q)\beta (1+sin(\frac{2\pi t}{12})) e \\
0 & q\beta (1+sin(\frac{2\pi t}{12})) e \end{array} \right),
 V(t)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\mu+k(1+sin(\frac{2\pi t}{12})) & 0  \\
-k(1+sin(\frac{2\pi t}{12})) & \mu+d+r  \end{array} \right).
$$

Where all the above letters are positive constants and $t$ is time.

The system has period 1. I will offer compensation to the individual who calculates the monodromy matrix step by step.

I have values for a lot of the parameters if that helps!

Comment: The system has period $12$. Surely you are aware that to build the monodromy  matrix you need to take a complex time. The only singularity   of your system is located at $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere. Hence all solutions are entire and the monodromy is trivial.  If you try to formulate your post as a question (which is the way this site works), maybe you could think over that point. Also, I believe the offer for «compensation» could be omitted altogether.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by all solutions are entire and that the monodromy matrix is trivial

Comment: The solutions are entire as holomorphic functions of the complex variable $t$. The solutions are not multivalued, so that the monodromy is trivial. If what you really want is to study existence of liouvillian («closed-form») solutions, then you're naked in the woods because the singularity at infinity is an essential singularity and no differential Galois theory exists in that case (as far as I know). Please, consider taking my previous comment in consideration and rewrite your post so that it asks a question which is research-level.

Comment: I'd be keen to know what is meant here by *compensation* since the OP has a rep of 1.

Comment: Cash or gift certificate, I have values of the majority of the parameters above which would reduce computation

Comment: There seem to be two cases that I can handle: 1st case : k -> 0, q -> 1, the system is uncoupled and trivial, and 2nd case : k -> 0, q -> 0, the system is coupled and a bit more complex. Is this acceptable? If so, in which case are you interested?